# Connecting a db that is several levels under ssh

Tags: shell, ssh

In order to reach the Cassandra I have to enter:

```
ssh dev@001.company.net
```

Then:

```
ssh dev@another-one.company.net
```

Then again:

```
ssh dev-test-001.company.net
```

I am trying to connect a Hackolade utility to render the DB in UI. How do I connect to it? Is there a certain procedure I have to follow to reach the DB located several `ssh`'s down?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ProxyJump` option, or its command-line option `-J`:

```
ssh -J dev@001.company.net,dev@another-one.company.net dev-test-001.company.net
```

Put more briefly, `ssh -J B,C A` connects to A by first connecting to B, then to C from B, before finally connecting to A from C.

If you put the following in your `.ssh/config` file,

```
Host dev-test-001.company.net
  ProxyJump dev@001.company.net,dev@another-one.company.net
```

then `ssh dev-test-001.company.net` will suffice to set up all the necessary intermediate connections.